# Specify a different R engine using options in rmarkdown chunks

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm using rmarkdown and i would like some R chunks to submitted to a remote server. I have written an engine for this but i dont want a different name since i want R's syntax highlighting to be kept for this engine.

So i thought i might have something like

````
```{r remoteAPI=TRUE}


```
````

And then i could override `knitr::knit_engines$get()$r` and call the default engine if `remoteAPI` is missing or FALSE. However there isn't a default engine for R.

1. So, how would i manually override the execution of  R chunks without another engine.
2. Or if i need to write another engine, e.g. remoteR, how can tell knitr to use R syntax for highlighting the output.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is trivial. Just before the return in your engine, set
`options$engine='r'`. See https://github.com/saptarshiguha/rdatabricks/blob/master/R/knitr_engines.R#L36